# web app to draw asterisk tree

Tags: c#

I'm working on a project in which i'm trying to use a webform to create the classic asterisk tree, using C# language.

The idea is to have a textbox where a number can be inserted and clicking a button produces an asterisk tree, in which the number of lines/branches is the number inserted in the textbox.

I've worked out a solution, but instead of a tree, the result i get is a line of asterisks with spaces between. I'm guessing there's a 
 missing somewhere but i can't figure out what's wrong...

```html
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int i = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
            string str = "";
            string str1 = "";
            Label1.Text = "";
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {

                str1 = "";
                for (int l = 0; l <= i - j; l++)
                {
                    str = str + " ";
                }
                for (int m = 0; m <= (j - 1); m++)
                {
                    str1 = str1 + "*";
                }
                for (int k = 0; k <= j; k++)
                {
                    str = str + "*";
                }
                str = str + str1 + System.Environment.NewLine;
            }
            Label1.Text = str;
        }
```

>

As a result instead of having something like * *** ***** *******, how can i create new lines?

Comment: google `MSDN new string()` method overloads you could do something like thing 
`var txtSep = new string('*', 12);` for new line just write 
`txtSep += Environment.NewLine()` for example in your spare time look up `+=` and how to use it.. or `string.Join()` ` method or string.Concat<>`

Comment: You probably need to append `"<br />"` and not `Environment.NewLine` if this is a web application.

Comment: i've tried to add <br/> instead of .NewLine but still no go...thank you for the suggestion anyway.